# How to use a foreach loop in PHP to get array elements

Tags: php, html, arrays

So I have this PHP function:

```
function getHurrList() {
    $sql = "SELECT HURR
            FROM HURRDURR";
    return DBIface::connect()->query($sql);
}
```

and I want to make a custom drop-down box that will display the list of hurrs that are accessed from the database.

```
<select name="hurr">
<?php   
    foreach (getHurrList() as $hurrValue){
        echo '<option value="';
        echo $hurrValue;
        echo '">';
        echo $hurrValue;
        echo "</option>";
    }

?>
</select>
```

When this code is run, what happens is that I get a drop-down list, where each option comes up as 'Array'. How can I fix the foreach loop or replace it with something else so that each HURR in HURRDURR is displayed in the drop-down list on the page?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are selecting the field named `HURR`, use that in your loop and not use the whole record array.

```
foreach (getHurrList() as $hurrValue)
   echo '<option value="{$hurrValue['HURR']}">{$hurrValue['HURR']}</option>';
```

Which is equivalent to

```
foreach (getHurrList() as $hurrValue){

    echo '<option value="';
    echo $hurrValue['HURR'];
    echo '">';
    echo $hurrValue['HURR'];
    echo "</option>";
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Absolutely fantastic.